# 3 main div side by side with 2 different percentage

Tags: html, css

I have the following split among 3 main div to be side by side. The very left div I want it to take up 60% of the screen and the rest 2 (description and resource) to take each 20%. When I run this all 3 are overlapping on the left portion. Below is my codes.

```
<div id="left" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:60%;height:100%;background:#e6e6e6;">
   <div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:60%;height:400px">Map goes here.</div>
   <div id="details" style="position:absolute;top:400px;left:0px;width:60%;height:400px">Details</div>  
  </div>
   <div id="description" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:20%;height:100%;background:#ffffff;">


   </div>
   <div id="resource" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:20%;height:100%;background:#ffffff;">

   </div>
```

Comment: They all have `top:0; left:0`, which means they will be placed at the same location... [Learning the basics of CSS positioning](http://learnlayout.com/) would really help you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute position and left being 0 is making them overlap.

**Please use css**

see solution : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/vZ77e/

**html**

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="map">Map goes here.</div>
    <div id="details">Details</div>
</div>
<div id="description">description</div>
<div id="resource">resource</div>
```

**css**

```
#left, #description, #resource{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}

#left{
    width:60%;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}

#description, #resource{
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: For the other I dont need to specify as float left is it? Just the first div? How will display:inline help ?

Comment: Display inline and float left will make sure all your divs are next to each other (side by side)

Comment: I read the link say this The element generates one or more inline element boxes. ? So what boxes it mean ? If I dont have the inline will that be fine?

Comment: inline is the default value so it should do!

Answer (score 1):

They are overlapping because you've given them all absolute position and left 0. Absolute position removes the element from the normal flow of the page and puts it exactly where you indicate using the top/left/right/bottom properties. They will overlap as long as they have the same parent and same position properties.

Comment: So, how can he fix it?

Answer (score 0):

They are overlapping because you are using position absolute. instead place the divs at the top of the html page and do this instead:

```
<div id="left" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;background:#e6e6e6;">
<div id="map" style="float:left;width:60%;height:400px">Map goes here.</div>
<div id="details" style="float:left;left:0px;width:60%;height:400px">Details</div>  
</div>
<div id="description" style="float:left;width:20%;height:100%;background:#ffffff;">


 </div>
<div id="resource" style="float:left;width:20%;height:100%;background:#ffffff;">

 </div>
```

This will place the divs beside each other

Comment: Thank you I will try and revert soon